# Creating repeating values using numpy.repeat

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, repeat

I am Python newbie and trying to replicate an R script of the following form in Python.

```
# set value for k
k <- 3

# script 1 R
cnt <- c(1,-1, rep(0,k-2))

print(cnt)
1 -1  0

# script 2 R
for (i in 2:(k-1)) {
  cnt <- c(cnt, c(rep(0,(i-1)),1,-1,rep(0,(k-i-1))))
    }

print(cnt)
1 -1  0  0  1 -1
```

In the `script 2` the outcome of `script 1` prefixed via concatenation. Given that Python doesn't have a direct equivalent to `Rs rep()` function, this
is what I have attempted to do, using `numpy.repeat`.

For `R script 1`, I did the following, which got me close to the desired outcome `1 -1 0`,

```
# code 1 Python
pcnt = np.array([1, -1, np.repeat('0', k-2)], dtype=int)

print(pcnt)
[ 1 -1  0]
```

but with a `` DeprecationWarning: setting an array element with a sequence. This was supported in some cases where the elements are arrays with a single element. For example `np.array([1, np.array([2])], dtype=int)`. In the future this will raise the same ValueError as `np.array([1, [2]], dtype=int) ``.

For `R script 2` I tried the following, but excluded the concatenation part with the intention of concatenating them after.

```
# code 2 Python
for i in range(2, k-1+1):
    pcnt2 = np.array([np.repeat(0, (i-1)), 1, -1, np.repeat(0, (k-i-1))], dtype='int')
print(pcnt2)
```

The above code raises a `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (4,) + inhomogeneous part.`

However, when I change `dtype='object'` like so

```
for i in range(2, k-1+1):
    pcnt3 = np.array([np.repeat(0, (i-1)), 1, -1, np.repeat(0, (k-i-1))], dtype='object')
print(pcnt3)
```

I get:

```
array([array([0]), 1, -1, array([], dtype=int32)], dtype=object)
```

What I need help with is how to get two separate arrays from both Python codes, with `code 1 Python` resulting in the following output `1 -1 0` and `code 2 Python` outputting `0 1 -1`

Comment: can you explain what you try to achieve independently of the R code?

Comment: it's to create a contrast matrix

Comment: I meant to explain the detailed logic of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `repeat` makes an array.

If we try to make a new array with integers and an array, we get:

```
In [23]: np.array([1,2,np.array([3,4])])
<ipython-input-23-77cecd77c763>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  np.array([1,2,np.array([3,4])])
Out[23]: array([1, 2, array([3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

Note that the result is a 3 element object dtype array; what the warning calls a 'ragged' sequence.

If we specify the `int` dtype, I get (in the latest verison) the error that your warning was talking about:

```
In [24]: np.array([1,2,np.array([3,4])],dtype=int)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [24] in <cell line: 1>
    np.array([1,2,np.array([3,4])],dtype=int)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (3,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

I suspect what you want is to `concatenate`, join the integers and the array into one flat array.  `hstack` makes that easy:

```
In [25]: np.hstack([1,2,np.array([3,4])])
Out[25]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

or

```
In [26]: np.concatenate([[1,2],np.array([3,4])])
Out[26]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Your `R` code uses `c`, which from its docs is a `concatenate`, `objects to be concatenated.`

`np.array` is not `concatenate`, though for certain lists of lists it does act like a concatenate, but on a new axis, as in the classic:

```
In [27]: np.array([ [1,2], [3,4]])
Out[27]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
In [28]: np.stack([ [1,2], [3,4]])
Out[28]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: #hpaulj, based on your wonderful comments and suggestions, this is what I ended up with and it works. ```# k

# intial array
cnt = np.concatenate([[1, -1], np.repeat(0, k-2)])

# concat previous array
for i in range(2, k-1+1):
    cnt = np.concatenate([pcnt, np.repeat(0, (i-1)), [1, -1], np.repeat(0, (k-i-1))])
print(cnt)```